Apache Ignite OOM on Server Nodes During DataStreamer Load with Cache Inconsistencies on Reconnect
I'm experiencing OOM (Out of Memory) issues on Apache Ignite server nodes in my Kubernetes cluster. Here’s a brief overview of my setup and the issue I’m facing:
Setup

Environment: Kubernetes
Apache Ignite Version: 2.16
Java 17
Cluster Configuration:
2 server nodes, each with 8 GB heap and 14 GB RAM.
1 client node used for data uploading.
Data Loading: Using Ignite's DataStreamer API to load data via the client node. During loading data via Client, more than 100 Ignite Caches are created and data are distributed between them.
Cache Configuration: each configured cache with Atomic mode, Partitioned, and 1 backup.

Issues
Issue OOM Errors on Server Nodes
When I start uploading data (~1GB per file, I had ~15 GBs in total) via the DataStreamer, one of the server nodes quickly goes OOM and disconnects from the cluster.
Shortly afterward, the second server node also goes OOM and disconnects.
Reconnection Error - Cache Inconsistency:
After the first server node attempts to reconnect to the cluster, it throws an exception: Joining node has caches which are not present on a cluster.
All caches have the same configuration, and I expected them to be present across the cluster consistently.
Questions

How can I prevent OOM when using DataStreamer with a large number of caches? Are there specific configurations or tuning options I should be using to control memory usage more effectively?
What causes the "Joining node has caches which are not present on a cluster" error on reconnect? Is there a way to ensure cache consistency across the cluster, even after nodes experience OOM or disconnects?


I can't say for sure what is causing the OOM error. I will say that it is highly unusual for this to happen after only 1 GB of total data loading. One item that you did not detail is if these 2 nodes are on the same physical host or not? If they are on separate physical hosts then this is even more unusual. If the are not on separate physical hosts, then you are getting no value from having 2 nodes!

@user21160483 Sorry, 1 GB per file of data, in total ~ 15-20GBs

OK, you are exceeding your available memory! You indicate that you have 2 nodes with 14 GB of memory. You also indicate that you are using a cache with 1 backup. And lastly you indicate that you are trying to load 15 - 20 GB of data into the above. If you have 15 GB of data with 1 backup then you need 30+ GB of memory to hold that 15 GB of data. If the data is 20 GB in total then you need 40+ GB of memory to hold that data with 1 backup! In short you are exceeding your available memory. Either expand the number of node (more memory) or double your memory on each node!

@user21160483 it would be true if I had in-memory Cluster type, but I have enabled persistence for it, so it must write data on checkpoint to FS. It does so, but Heap is still overloaded. Is there way that number of caches (100+) can influence it? I know about cache group, but it says that if you have +-100 caches it has no influence: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/cache-groups

you should consider that the total amount of memory required for the node consists of 3 parts: heap + direct buffers (could allocate up to a heap size in case not limited by the MaxDirectMemorySize JVM option) + offheap (which is a sum of max sizes for all configured data regions, even in the case of enabled persistence). In case you don't have direct buffers limited you can easily exceed the available 14 GB RAM limit. See additional details here: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/perf-and-troubleshooting/memory-tuning
